# Iron-resize event issues on non-Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, polymer, window-resize

I am working on a single page app using Polymer framework version 1.x. I've created a responsive element, which computes number of columns depending on the width. I use Polymer.IronResizableBehavior which fires iron-resize event when the window is resized.

Here are the important snippets of code:

```
        listeners: {
            'iron-resize': '_onWidthChange'
        },

        _onWidthChange: function () {
            var numberOfColumns,
                w = this.$.animated_calendar.offsetWidth;

            if (w > 0) {
                numberOfColumns = w / 100 >> 0;
                if (numberOfColumns > 7) numberOfColumns = 7;
                else if (numberOfColumns === 0) numberOfColumns = 1;
                this.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
            }
        },
```

The issue is that I get 0 width when the element is first rendered on Firefox and IE. When I resize the window then the function is called again and a proper offsetWidth is received.

I could create a workaround, which would get a browser type if the width was 0 and by that determine if it's desktop or not and set the numberOfColumns accordingly. However it would be quite messy and the behavior wouldn't be ideal.

I hope I will get a correct behavior when the Polymer 2.0 comes out (it is supposed to be released in Q1), but I need to get it working now so thank you for advises.